# Duplicate values and group by throwing query results off

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to execute a query and having some issues.  The objective is to find all duplicate values for a specific field (Upc) that manufacturers (idPub) are using.  An example is manufacturer A uses upc 1010 while manufacture B also occupies upc 1010.  This data is stored in one table.  So far, I've come up with this query below...

```
USE dbIdwWhseLC

SELECT tbItem.sUpc, COUNT(*) AS NumberofDups
FROM tbItem
WHERE sUpc IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY sUpc
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

The query is displaying the correct data as far as upc numbers and counts, however when attempting to throw the manufacturer field in the query, I have to group by that manufacturer field too which is throwing the results off.  I'm trying to the query to return data like this below...

```
Upc         idPub

1010        A

1010        B
```

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to take this query as a subquery, and select the other fields you want in the outer query restricting the rows of the outer query to the ones that match the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join back to your main table, like so:

```
WITH Duplicates AS
(
Select tbItem.sUpc
,COUNT(*) As NumberofDups
From tbItem
Where sUpc is not null
Group by sUpc
Having COUNT(*)>1
)
SELECT
D.sUpc
,TI.idPub
,M.[name]
FROM
Duplicates AS D
INNER JOIN
tblItem AS TI
ON
D.sUpc = TI.sUpc
INNER JOIN 
tbMfrReporting AS M
ON
TI.nIdPub = M.nIdPub
```

The Duplicates statement above is known as a CTE.

I hope that helps.

Ash

EDIT: query updated to add further table as per comments

Comment: I believe the CTE is returning the results I need.  Thanks very much.  However if I wanted to perform another inner join statement in there, how would I go about?

Comment: Inner join tbMfrReporting  On tbItemTxt.nIdPub = tbMfrReporting.nIdPub

Comment: geez sorry about the unfinished comments...I keep hitting enter.  basically tbMfrReporting contains a field (name) which is just the name of the manufacturer (nIdpub).  thanks again.

Comment: the updated query is returning the name, however the number of records differ than the original query you supplied me with.  I've also noticed on a few that were displaying correctly before the name field was thrown in the mix are now not showing.  any ideas?  for example, the upc '1010' is tied to two different manufacturers, however when the name field was thrown in the query, it's now being returned in the query but only displaying with one manufacturer.

Comment: Please disregard last comment...I overlooked something.  This query worked very well.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find all the entries where the upc is in the list of UPCs that have more than one entry, so...

```
select sUpc, idPub
from tbItem
where sUpc in 
(
    Select tbItem.sUpc
    From tbItem
    Where sUpc is not null
    Group by sUpc
    Having COUNT(*)>1
)
```